# Do Bloody Assault and Bleeding Attack stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

I was wondering if Bloody Assault and Bleeding Attack stack with each other. They both say that they don't stack with themselves but neither specifies whether it stacks with other bleeding effects.

Comment: [Possibly related question on bleeding](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27433/for-the-bleeding-critical-feat-what-stacks-exactly?rq=1)

Comment: Well in that bleeding critical says it does stack with itself I was more confused that bleed dmg says it's only stacks while dealing different dmg and and that these two here say they just don't stack with them selves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bloody Assault feat and Bleeding Attack talent both deal the same type of bleed (HP), so they do not stack. You take the highest value, which in this case is generally Bleeding Attack (which scales on your sneak attack dice).

[Source](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#conditions)

> Bleed: A creature that is taking bleed damage takes the listed amount of damage at the beginning of its turn. Bleeding can be stopped by a DC 15 Heal check or through the application of any spell that cures hit point damage (even if the bleed is ability damage). Some bleed effects cause ability damage or even ability drain. Bleed effects do not stack with each other unless they deal different kinds of damage. When two or more bleed effects deal the same kind of damage, take the worse effect. In this case, ability drain is worse than ability damage.

Comment: In regards to Bleeding Critical, the bleed value inflicted by this feat would only stack with itself, if there was another HP bleed effect already then they would suffer the highest amount. If this would be another bleed effect then the bleed from Bleeding Critical is lost.